# How does `sum (replicate 5 (max 6.7 8.9))` and `(sum . replicate 5 . max 6.7) 8.9` get the same result?

Tags: haskell, operators, decimal-point, function-composition

Rewrite `(sum . replicate 5 . max 6.7) 8.9` using function composition. We have

`(sum . replicate 5 . max 6.7) 8.9`

I understand the part `(sum . replicate 5 . max 6.7)`. But then how does it deal with `8.9`?

*edit from comments:* turns out, the `.` in `6.7` is not a function composition operator, but a decimal dot!

Comment: Do you understand how `(max 6.7) 8.9` works?

Comment: Not quite understand. I know how `(max 6) 7` works

Comment: @user8314628: the `.` is `6.7` is *not* function composition, it is the decimal dot.

Comment: Ahhh... That was silly-,-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write `f . g`, this is basically short for `\x -> f (g x)`. Since the `(.)` operator is right associative your function is equivalent to:

```
=    (sum . replicate 5 . max 6.7) 8.9
--------------------------------------
   (sum . (replicate 5 . max 6.7)) 8.9
```

and:

```
=                    (sum . (replicate 5 . max 6.7)) 8.9
--------------------------------------------------------
   (\x -> sum ((\y -> (replicate 5 (max 6.7 y))) x)) 8.9
```

So now if we perform evaluation, we see:

```
=  (\x -> sum ((\y -> (replicate 5 (max 6.7 y))) x)) 8.9
--------------------------------------------------------
             sum ((\y -> (replicate 5 (max 6.7 y))) 8.9)
```

and:

```
=  sum ((\y -> (replicate 5 (max 6.7 y))) 8.9)
----------------------------------------------
               sum (replicate 5 (max 6.7 8.9))
```

So the function composition will first place the `8.9` as second parameter of the `max`, and then apply all other functions to the result in some sort of chain from right-to-left.

Answer (score 3):

`max 6.7` takes a `Double` and returns a `Double`. `replicate 5` takes a `Double` and makes a `[Double]`. `sum` takes a `[Double]` and returns something of type `Double`. (after type inference.)

`.` just chains all of these functions together, so you're left with a function of type `Double -> Double`. Then you pass `8.9` to that function.

Answer (score 1):

If you understand the part `(sum . replicate 5 . max 6.7)` then you know that it returns a function that sums the maximum number of 6.7 and given number replicated 5 times. The type of this new function is Float -> Float.

So next we apply 8.9 to this function and we get final value. We can write it in more intuitive way:

```
mySum :: Float -> Float
mySum = sum . replicate 5 . max 6.7

result :: Float
result = mySum 8.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions in Haskell are curried. A curried function that otherwise takes two parameter values you can use with only one.

```
f = max 2
f 3
```

3

When you write `max 2 3` it is actually translated into (max 2) with a parameter 3, (max 2) 3 is what Haskell is doing anyway.

This lends itself to point-free code. You do not have to specify the final parameter of a function or function composition but do have to supply it when calling the function or functions composition.